# Neovim - blend transparent highlight colors

Tags: vimrc, neovim, colorscheme, plugin-nvimtree

I am trying to make the NvimTree background a different color than the main neovim window, while retaining transparency set by Alacritty. The desired panel can be made fully transparent with :highlight NvimTreeNormal guibg=none, or fully green with :highlight NvimTreeNormal guibg=#00FF00, but vim does not support RGBA colors and adding the blend= option has no effect.

Is it possible to set/blend a specific highlight color to a darker shade while maintaining transparency? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.s]! I suspect this is not possible, but I'm not an expert in these things, so hopefully one can weigh in and explain why or why not/how.